# shutdown command: what is the scenario(s) or purpose(s) to use the -k option?

Tags: command-line, shutdown

About `man shutdown` at:

- [shutdown(8) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/shutdown.8.html)

it indicates:

```
   ...
   -k
       Do not halt, power-off, reboot, just write wall message.       
   ...
```

Therefore as follows

```
shutdown +1 -k 
shutdown +1 -k "something to share"
```

I can confirm the other users that are logged receive - appears in their `tty` - the broadcast message (including or not the custom message according the case). Now, as the documentation indicates, when the time is reached nothing happens.

So, why send a message to all users about something that is not going to happen?. In some way it generates a confusion for them.

**Question**

- What is the scenario(s) or purpose(s) to use the `-k` option?

Comment: `shutdown -k "maint window 3AM-5AM starts now. Go home."` `$USER` goes away, system stays up for `root`.

Comment: @waltinator Interesting, but there is no warranty that the user really leaves and I assumed Linux has other command for broadcast purposes.

Comment: Yes - the documentation even mentions it: `wall`. If the user doesn't leave, then that's their work that might be lost. Ignoring a sysadmin's warning at your peril.

Comment: @muru - you are correct, but due for some reason - what happens if the user is working and appears the message and quickly due other work (the user was writing quickly) the message is gone?

Comment: What do you think will happen?

Comment: Consider this scenario - about the "wall message" not broadcast - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/699327/shutdown-command-why-the-wall-message-is-not-broadcast-to-all-logged-users-if