# shutdown command: why the "wall message" is not broadcast to all logged users if the time is equals or greater than 16 minutes?

Tags: command-line, systemd, shutdown

About `man shutdown` at:

- [shutdown(8) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/shutdown.8.html)

it indicates:

```
   ...
   The first argument may be a time string (which is usually "now").
   Optionally, this may be followed by a wall message to be sent to
   all logged-in users before going down.
   ...
   Note that to specify a wall message you must specify a time
   argument, too.
   ...
```

**Note** this post is about the *wall message* to be broadcast to all the logged users.

Therefore using the following pattern as follows:

```
shutdown <time> ["something to share"]
```

Where `<time>` can be +1, ... +5, ... +15, therefore from the `+1` to `+15` **range** - it as follows:

```
shutdown +1 ["something to share"]
...
shutdown +5 ["something to share"]
...
shutdown +15 ["something to share"]
```

I can confirm the other users that are logged receive - appears in their `tty` - the broadcast message (including or not the custom message according the case). Therefore as the documentation indicates, the message is broadcast. Until here no reason to create this post.

**Situation**: the reason, I did realise - if `<time>` is *equals* or *greater than* **16** minutes - used through either `+16` or `hh:mm` the message is **not** broadcast to the other logged users in their `tty`. For example if `date` command returns `00:10` then with `shutdown 00:26 ...` this situation happens. Of course, if is used `shutdown 00:15` all work as expected.

**Question**

- Why the *wall message* is not broadcast to all logged users if the time is equals or greater than 16 minutes? - Is it normal or is a bug?

Through either the `man shutdown` or `shutdown --help`  theoretically the *wall message* must be always broadcast to all the logged users, it does not matter the range of time about *"from now"* +15, +20 etc ...

**Note** I have this situation in many Virtual Machines - for different hosts - for Ubuntu Server 20.04

Comment: Did you try to see what happens if you use `shutdown +20` and wait five minutes? I haven't tried that in a while so not sure, but I seem to recall it walls more often when time is running out and more rarely (or not at all) when there's more time left.

Comment: I added the systemd tag, because this is relevant only for systemd (which Ubuntu 20.04 uses), as I wrote at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information is buried in `systemd`'s sources in [`src/login/logind-utmp.c`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v245/src/login/logind-utmp.c):

[Warn immediately if less than 15 minutes are left](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v245/src/login/logind-utmp.c#L142) (when the command is run):

```c
/* Warn immediately if less than 15 minutes are left */
if (elapse - n < 15 * USEC_PER_MINUTE) {
        r = warn_wall(m, n);
        if (r == 0)
                return 0;
}
```

As for when there are warning sent at other times, it's a [fixed list of possible remaining minutes before action](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v245/src/login/logind-utmp.c#L26):

```c
static const int wall_timers[] = {
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
        25, 40, 55, 70, 100, 130, 150, 180,
};
```

So if you run for example (`-k` for fake):

```
shutdown -k +41 test; sleep 62; shutdown -c
```

You'll see a broadcast shutdown message 1mn after and it will be cancelled 2 more seconds after. Using `-k +40` won't send a message immediately though.

---

The systemd variant of [`shutdown(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/shutdown.8.html) only tells:

> Optionally, this may be followed by a wall message to be **sent** to all
> logged-in users **before going down**.

It doesn't document that such message will be *sent when the command is run* or repeated before shutdown (even if it is), only that it will be *sent before going down*.

By comparision the [sysvinit `shutdown`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/sysvinit-core/shutdown.8.en.html#q) was documented differently and hopefully the implementation followed the documentation:

> `-q`
>
> Reduce the number of warnings shutdown displays. Usually shutdown
> displays warnings every 15 minutes and then every minute in the last
> 10 minutes of the countdown until time is reached. When `-q` is
> specified shutdown only warns at 60 minute intervals, at the 10 minute
> mark, at the 5 minue mark, and when the shutdown process actually
> happens.

Comment: Huge thanks, valuable the code shared. - Pls consider give your support about the `-k` option at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/699323/shutdown-command-what-is-the-scenarios-or-purposes-to-use-the-k-option

Comment: I saw the other question later, but imho its answer can't just rely about solid facts (sources) like this one. So I'd rather not attempt. My example of `-k` use looks to me like what it's intended for: testing.